# How do I collect daily login statistics

Tags: users

I am trying to add a contest to my website which will be based on how frequently they login into my website. Each user will be assigned one point per day irrespective of how many times the login in a day. A winner will be picked every month, at random, based on the number of times they have logged in. Hence the more times you login, the more odds you have of winning.

Any ideas on what would be the best approach? Would I have to build a module from scratch? Modify a current module? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to recommend the [Login History](http://drupal.org/project/login_history) module to track logins on the site -- then it's just a simple matter of doing some filtering and reporting logic to see how many days a user has a login recorded for.

For instance Views and [Views Aggregate](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) could likely help build list of tally's; as @rooby says [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) could then do emailing and other tasks for you.

**EDIT**

views integration seems to be incomplete on the original module in an issue, but there is a small support module that adds the functionality while the issue is worked on the in parent module: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mouhammed/2396263

Answer (score 2):

I would say use the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module along with the [User Points Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_login) add-on module to handle to recording of points for users logging in.

Then you can use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to build reports for yourself to see which users have the most points for a given period.

It would also be possible to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to automatically email you a report of the winners at the end of every month and then reset all user points to zero (I'm making an assumption that there is a rules action you could use to remove existing user points).

Comment: Userpoints is a bit of a heavier solution however it allows you to assign points for other site interactions. If the "points" will only be seen by you and you only need login stats then tenken's answer of using the Login History module is probably better because it is a more light weight solution.